# Trigger logic and/or VR for identfying the Case form and related list record?

Tags: apex, trigger, validation-rule

I am trying to write the **Validation Rule** OOTB or trigger to accomplish the following functionality but doesn't succeeded yet.

I have a `Type` field on the Child object called as `Authorization`, which has master detailed relationship with `Case` object. All VF and Controller developed are custom. On the form. `Type` field is created on the `Authorization`. and on the same form I have a related list section. When I click on new related list button then the form will open, on that form I have another field `Authorization Date`.

VR - When **Type=Partial Refund**, then **AuthorizationDate** is mandatory. How we can write VR or trigger to identify if its a Case form or related list form ?

When related list record will be created, if Type=Partial Refund the Authorization Date becomes mandatory.

```
public static void ValidationTypeCheck(List<Authorization__c> newauth, Map<Id,Case> caseMap){
    for(Authorization__c auth : newauth){

        if(caseMap.get(auth.Case__c).Type__c == 'Partial Refund'){

            if(caseMap.get(auth.Case__c).Category__c == 'Auth' && caseMap.get(auth.Case__c).SubCategory__c == 'Basic Auth'){
                System.debug('~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~:: '+auth.Type__c);
                if(String.isEmpty(auth.AuthrizationDate__c)){
                    auth.AuthrizationDate__c.addError('XXXXXXXXXXXX');
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Below also doesn't works !

```
AND 
( 
ISPICKVAL(Case__c.Category__c, 'Auth'), 
ISPICKVAL(Case__c.SubCategory__c, 'Basic Auth'), 
ISPICKVAL(Type__c , 'Partial Refund'), 
NOT(ISNEW()), 
ISBLANK( TEXT( AuthorizationDate__c )) 
)
```

Comment: Are you creating new Authorization__c records? Because your Validation Rule does not check against new records.

Comment: Yes, creating a Authorization__c when Case is creating and when Related List for Authorization__c also creating

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you have provided I would simply update your validation rule so that it does not exclude new records.

```
Not(IsNew()) to IsNew()
```

Your visualforce code will only check records that are not new so if you want to check certain criteria on the create you will need to open up the validation rule so that it can check newly created records as well. If you want to check on create and update then I would take out the `IsNew()` part of the validation rule all together.

Comment: Nopes, its not working...

Comment: Have you tried to change ISBLANK( TEXT( AuthorizationDate__c )) to ISBLANK(AuthorizationDate__c )?